# Why do integers in PowerShell compare by digits?

Tags: powershell, comparison, operators

My code tells you whether your guessed number is higher or lower than a randomly generated number, but it seems to only compare the first digits of the number when one of them is below 10.

```
[int]$GeneratedNum = Get-Random -min 1 -max 101
Write-Debug $GeneratedNum

$isQuitting = $false
Do{
    [int]$Input = Read-Host "Take a guess!"

    If($Input -lt $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Too Low"}
    If($Input -gt $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Too High"}
    If($Input -eq $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Good Job!"; $isQuitting = $true}

} Until($isQuitting -eq $true)
```

For example, when the `$GeneratedNum = 56` and `$Input = 7`, it returns `"Too High"`

Comment: The value read from `Read-Host` is a string not an integer. Your variable marker isn't a cast it would seem. Use a cast on the right-hand side of the assignment and it seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because you're comparing a string to an integer. The order matters.

```psh
"56" -lt 7
```

Is actually the same as:

```psh
"56" -lt "7"
```

Alternatively:

```psh
56 -lt "7"
```

would give you the correct result. PowerShell tries to coerce the right side argument to the type of the left side.

You might try an explicit cast:

```psh
[int]$Input -lt $GeneratedNum
```

Answer (score 4):

The trouble come from the fact that `Read-Host` return  a string so with your cast `$Input` is an `ArrayListEnumeratorSimple` try :

```
[int]$GeneratedNum = Get-Random -min 1 -max 101
Write-host $GeneratedNum

$isQuitting = $false
Do{
    $Input = (Read-Host "Take a guess!") -as [int]

    If($Input -lt $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Too Low"}
    If($Input -gt $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Too High"}
    If($Input -eq $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Good Job!"; $isQuitting = $true}

} Until($isQuitting -eq $true)
```

You also should use `try{}catch{}` to catch the case the input is not an int.

The thing you must understand is that when you use PowerShell comparison operators, the type of the left part is used selected, so the rigth part is casted into the left type. Knowing that you could have write the following, where I just put the `$GeneratedNum` which is an integer on the left of the comparisons:

```
[int]$GeneratedNum = Get-Random -min 1 -max 101
Write-host $GeneratedNum

$isQuitting = $false
Do{
    $Input = (Read-Host "Take a guess!")

    If($GeneratedNum -gt $Input){Write-Output "Too Low"}
    If($GeneratedNum -lt $Input){Write-Output "Too High"}
    If($GeneratedNum -eq $Input){Write-Output "Good Job!"; $isQuitting = $true}

} Until($isQuitting -eq $true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use a variable with the same name as an automatic variable: `$input` is an automatic variable.

See this code, where I pipe the value read from host (and don't use the `$input` variable):

```
[int]$GeneratedNum = Get-Random -min 1 -max 101
Write-Debug $GeneratedNum
$isQuitting = $false
Do{
    Read-Host "Take a new guess!" | %{

        if($_ -as [int] -gt 0){
            If($_ -lt $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Too Low"}
            If($_ -gt $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Too High"}
            If($_ -eq $GeneratedNum){Write-Output "Good Job!"; $isQuitting = $true}
        }
    }

} Until($isQuitting -eq $true)
```

Important to notice that my code treats correctly **wrong** inputs (non numeric characters) like `w` or like strings (`qwerty`), which make the other proposals to fail.

I make use of the fact that you generate integers **always** greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `switch`:

```
[int]$GeneratedNum = Get-Random -min 1 -max 101
Write-Debug $GeneratedNum

:lop Do{
    switch ((Read-Host 'Take a new guess!') -as [int])
    {
        {$_ -eq $null}{continue}
        {$_ -lt $GeneratedNum}{'Too Low';continue}
        {$_ -gt $GeneratedNum}{'Too High';continue}
        {$true}{'Good Job!';break lop}
    }

} while($true)
```