# Incorrect Operator Result in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, operators

So this seems really simple, and it's really easy to guess the result, but I seem to be getting a really wierd result in powershell.

So essentially I'm building an array with an unknown number of objects in there, then running an operator against the .Count property.

Example:

```bsh
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$n = 0

while ($n -ne 27) {$n++; $a.Add("Test line")}

# Array built, the .Count property should be 27

$bool = $false
$number = 2

if ($number -gt $a.Count) {$bool = $true}

# This correctly gives me $bool as $false

$number = 3

if ($number -gt $a.Count) {$bool = $true}

# This incorrectly gives me $bool as $true, and does so when $number is
# greater than 3.
```

Any ideas on this? I've never seen this before. Above is a simplified example, but essentially I'm pulling objects into an array, getting user input with `Read-Host` and I want to compare if the user input is greater than (`-gt`) the total count of the array.

Comment: Example above is working as expected, Is it possible you're running your script in ISE where for some reason $bool value you perceive as incorrect is stored between runs? Or is it possible that in your original code you set $bool value between checks and only assume $bool was assigned as a result of that particular check? Try adding into your code statements to display $bool values after each part of code or use breakpoints in ISE to narrow down where this incorrect value is coming from.

Comment: The ISE will preserve variable values between script execution. Whereas the console does not, unless of course the variables scope is modified.

Comment: Good suggestions. I am writing this in ISE, but have confirmed this happens when run in the powershell console too. Variable is not saved between runs, have used breakpoints, I'm even using Write-Host to write the value of each variable at each step. I'm confirming that if $number is 0, 1 or 2, the it works correctly. But if it's more than 3, it is behaving incorrectly. I've just tested again and I feel I'm going crazy!

Comment: Update: I changed the .Count to 47, and tried $number as 3. This works now, but then changing $number to 4, it happens again. It looks like for some reason the Powershell operators are only comparing to the first digit in the .Count property. I'm so lost

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [Why do integers in PowerShell compare by digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146984/why-do-integers-in-powershell-compare-by-digits)

Added [int] markers to the variables and now works perfectly. Thanks for the suggestions.